# Handle exceptions in Azure timer functions

Tags: azure-functions

I have a timer function that runs every 15 minutes (pseudo-code below). Due to a vendor issue in the 3rd party service, we would see failures followed by stretches (45 minutes, 6 hours, etc.) where the timer function did not execute.

```
public static class ThirdPartySynchronization
{
    private static readonly ThirdPartySdk s_thirdPartySdk = new ThirdPartySdk();

    [FunctionName("TimerTriggerCSharp")]
    public static void Run([TimerTrigger("0 */5 * * * *")]TimerInfo myTimer, ILogger log)
    {
        try 
        {
            await s_thirdPartySdk.Synchronize();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            log.Error(ex.Message);
            throw;
        }
    }
}
```

When I run the function locally and hit the same error sate, the `throw` occasionally crashes the `func.exe` host, which made me wonder if a similar issue occurs in our Consumption Plan.

I don't see a lot of guidance in Azure's documentation or best practices for how to handle exceptions (or mark a timer function as non-success). Any recommended pattern for handling exceptional behavior in C# Azure timer functions?

Comment: If you are using consumption plan execution time can't be more then 10 minutes:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-scale#consumption-plan

Answer (score 1):

There is no guidlance for timertrigger:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-error-pages

Best what you can do:

1. Analyze function execution logs:
   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-monitoring
2. Manage function timeout: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-host-json#functiontimeout. For consumption plan it's 10 minutes max.